# Windows 10 crashes using blender

Tags: rendering, windows

I have tried to find an answer in internet on my issue before to write in this blog but I couldn't find any. I am currently using blender 2.90.1 and after rendering a complex scene I open a new Blender file and windows suddenly crash. I have the same issue with Blender 2.83. I am testing the software with 'The Junk Shop' scene. I have updated Windows with the latest updates but I think I have an issue with my GTX 1060 and windows doesn't update the latest graphic drivers as it was doing before.
Please see below the Computer info:[image][image]

I hope that some one can help me
Thanks

Comment: Try installing the latest stable version of blender.

Comment: Thanks Akai, I just tried Blender 2.83.5 with 'The Junk Shop' and in the viewport in Rendered mode the computer crashes when the render end. I really don't have any idea!

Comment: You can try to manually update the graphics driver for your [Nvidia GPU](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/165686/en-us) and [Intel GPU](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29957/Intel-Graphics-Windows-10-DCH-Drivers?product=97185).

Comment: Thanks Robert I will follow your advice

Comment: Hi Robert, I updated the drivers but unfortunately the situation is worst, now blender crashes when i try to open any files.

Comment: just to clarify the software crash only when I try to open the file from Blender.

Comment: Only Blender crashing instead of the entire operating system, would be an improvement though? With the currently provided information it's hard to tell where the problem is, I would need to take a look at the crash log and possibly additional debug logs. I suggest you try the workaround described in [this ticket](https://developer.blender.org/T78799) first.

Comment: Hi Robert thanks for your help. the problem Blender is all windows crash the operating system. i will try with blender 2.92

Comment: @1234stelle Just to make sure that there's no miscommunication (regarding program window or Windows the OS). Does only Blender close or is the entire computer crashing (blue screen, power off, automatic rebooting)?

Comment: Hi Robert, i just did a test also with 2.92 and Windows 10 crashes ( blue screen) I really don't understand, now all the drivers are updated for both Nvidia and Intel. Do you think is a Blender bug?

Comment: I don't know if this works but, try installing MSI AfterBurner and set the fanspeed to high and then apply changes then try using blender? Just give it a shot.

Comment: Thanks every body maybe i found the way. I uninstalled all the Nvidia driver and and install the following: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had to search better for the correct driver. there is a different between Descktop driver and Notebook driver. Thanks to everyone for your help

this looks the correct driver

[image]

https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx

for now it look that it is working properly

Thanks

Comment: That's my fault then, I've linked the desktop driver in my comment above. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hi Robert and everyone Blender is working better but not completely. Sometimes when I open a file from Blender the software works properly for a while but after few minutes the software crash and also Windows 10. I really don't understand why this still happens. At this point I don't know any more. If anyone what this is the link to download the blender file. https://we.tl/t-eihK87TJOM

Comment: I would suggest you check the Windows event log and/or note the error displayed on the blue screen, should Windows display one. You should be able to get more help with this information on a Windows forum. Blender in itself can't crash the operating system, so the issue must be somewhere else.

Comment: I started this file in blender 2.83 and I am currently using the 2.90.1